# How to check if 2 rows are the same and give suggested value based on another cell?

Tags: excel, ms-access

Here's my database filled with custom examples:

[image]

Basically, what I want to do, is if the "EAN" is the same in more than 1 rows AND their Value OR S_Unit are different (ID: 1 and 3), then give me a list somewhere in my document, or in an access table about these cases. 4 cases are possible:

[image]

If case 2 applies to any of these, I'd like my program to return something like this:

> "EAN: 12345" has different values or units: (0.1 L ; 0.4 KG). Which
>   one would you like to use?
>
> 1. Button 1: 0.1 L - Update query,
> 2. Button 2: 0.4 KG - Update query,
> 3. Button 3: None - Exit

I am not looking for someone to write this program for me obviously because there's no learning for me in that, but I don't know what exactly I want to do and where.

1. First step is obviously to check if there are same EANs and store them in a database
2. Next step is to check if these EANs have same values or s_units. And that's where it's kind of tricky for me unfortunately.

Could you please provide some kind of help that what is exactly I am looking for?

Thank you

Comment: The question is so broad. Perhaps users just make choice from combobox. Perhaps use VBA to present options in an InputBox popup. There's 2 starting points. Take your pick.

Comment: This is too broad, but for the second step, you could make a group query to count how many records does each EAN got, and second group query to count how many records does Each EAN, Value and S_Unit got. If the count of each EAN in both queries is the same, it would mean to do nothing. IF the count is not the same, then you will trigger the aditional options (and that opens a whole new world, and that's why I said this is too broad).